# How to monitor Voltage by a chip

Tags: voltage, current, electricity, circuits

I am making a circuit that would produce electric current.

My question is that is there exists any chip that can monitor Voltage and if there would be current at specific voltage, the current would not pass from the chip(it will act like a switch) and when the Voltage < specific Voltage, the current would pass?

Comment: Do you mean something like using a FET as a switch? Apologies if I misunderstood what you were asking

Comment: "there would be current at specific voltage" <- I don't understand that, though your English is very good! Can you give an example? Voltage is *potential difference*, so voltage across *what*?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I _think_ they're asking about some sort of overvoltage disconnect system.

Comment: @Felthry in that case, giving orders of magnitudes for voltages and current will be necessary even more!

Comment: @Felthry ! Exactly.

Comment: so, if that is the case, please deliver the voltages and currents we're dealing with. Your question really is inanswerable without that!

Comment: The voltage may be taken as 1V. @Marcus

Comment: I asked for voltage **and** current. You have to give us some sort of overall idea of what we're dealing with, or else we can't help you! Please, describe what you need to build in a way that would allow us to get a feeling for what you need. Imagine us knowing *exactly nothing* about your project. That is the reality. How are you expecting us to help?

Comment: Ok listen. I am making a project in which I am trying to make some kind of perpetual motion with a wheel inside which glass tubes of a chemical is filled. The moving phenomenon is clear but I want that I would attach a motor with the wheel and when the wheel woud be at fatal stage, it would be obvious that the voltage produced by the generator attached by wheel would become low and so if the VOLTAGE WOULD BE LOW, THERE WOULD BE A CIRCUIT WHICH WOULD MONITOR THE VOLTAGE AND IF VOLTAGE IS LOW, THE CIRCUIT WOULD ALLOW THE CURRENT TO PASS TO THE MOTOR WHICH WOULD GIVE A shock to the motor to start

Comment: By this the motor would spin the wheel again and the chemical inside the tube would ultimately start making current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a circuit called a comparator circuit that acts "as a switch when the voltage is at or above a certain level"

[Comparator Circuits](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html)

Now if you're wanting to monitor current, then you can use something like an INA168 with a buffer after going to an A/D.  These have the current to voltage calcs typically on the datasheet.